# How to grep an array index inside loop in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, unix

`cmd` is an array, I wanted to `grep` each index:

```
for i in "${cmd[@]}";
do
a=`deep status | grep "${cmd[$i]}" |  awk  '{print $2 ~ /RUNNING/}'
```

But this is not working `a` should contain either `1` or `0`, but I am getting no process:

```
cmd[@]: ERROR (no such process)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please edit your question and use "Code Sample" for greater readability.

Comment: The code is too incomplete to evaluate.  The `a` variable has no closing backtick, and there's no `done` statement.  What does `deep` do?

Comment: Add a shebang and then paste your script there: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Your question appears to be an **XY Problem**. See: [**What is the XY problem?**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Posting the actual information with input and output would likely result in a better proposed solution that would likely eliminate one or both pipes and the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You're iterating over the contents of the array then trying to use the element as an index. You need to use the element directly as the argument:

```
for i in "${cmd[@]}"
do
    a=$(deep status | awk -v my_var="$i" '$0 ~ my_var {print $2 ~ /RUNNING/}')
done
```

It is possible to iterate over the indices, then use the index in the array reference, but this is probably not necessary unless you need to do something with the indices themselves:

```
for i in "${!cmd[@]}"    # Note the "!"
do
    echo "$i"    # or some other operation using the index
    a=$(deep status | awk -v my_var="${cmd[$i]}" '$0 ~ my_var {print $2 ~ /RUNNING/}')
done
```

Note that it's not necessary to pipe `grep` into `awk` since the latter can do the the matching itself. I have used `$0` here, but you can be more specific if you know which field you're trying to match.

Also, repeatedly running the same command in a loop can be slow. Depending on how "deep status" works and the format of your array, you may be able to do the whole thing without the `for` loop.

And use `$()` instead of backticks. They're much more readable and more easily nested.

Comment: you can improve the `awk` script with: `awk "/${cmd[$i]}/{print \$2 ~ /RUNNING/}"`

Comment: @DudiBoy: That's not an improvement. It is better to pass variables into AWK using the `-v` option.